# Masking properties for Textview in android

Tags: android, transparentproxy

I have a `scrollView` in my `Activity`,the background of `scrollView` is of multiple colours.

```
<ScrollView ---------->
  <RelativeLayout -------------/>
</ScrollView>
```

To my `RelativeLayout` I have added Views dynamically.

inflated xml:

```
<RelativeLayout --------------android:background="some transparent image">
  <TextView --------- ---------/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want my Text coloured to be same as Background colour. I have tried for the solution in many ways but could not succeed.

In iOS for achieving this they have used `RSMaskedLabel` (third party class), but I didn’t find anything similar to this in Android.

Still I didnt find any solution,can anyone help me please. I tried by using Bitmaps and Canvas but didnt worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the Standard Android API. So you'll have to come up with something of your own. If you have problems with coding that, you can come back here and ask for help with your code.

Comment: I have seen ThirdPArty class RSMaskedLabel for iOS in Github,but I didnt find anything for android. I tried with giving transparent to Textview,but didnt workrd

Comment: https://github.com/robinsenior/RSMaskedLabel  here is the link of github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some guidelines how to achieve this with custom `TextView`:

1. Extend `TextView` component
2. Create `Bitmap` and `Canvas` where you draw background and text
3. Draw wanted background color into allocated `Canvas`(e.g. `Color.argb(80, 255, 255, 255)`)
4. Draw the text with `Paint` having mode `PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR)` (Remember: Only allocate `Bitmap` and `Canvas` once) since you draw it into `Bitmap`
5. Draw the `Bitmap` into `TextViews` canvas

Here is some sample code to get started with:

```
public class TransparentTextView extends TextView {

    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToDraw;

    public TransparentTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setup();
    }

    public TransparentTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setup();
    }

    public TransparentTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTextPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmapToDraw == null) {
            mBitmapToDraw = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            if (mBitmapToDraw != null) {
                Canvas c = new Canvas(mBitmapToDraw);

                c.drawColor(Color.argb(80, 255, 255, 255));

                c.drawText(getText().toString(), getPaddingLeft(),
                        getPaddingTop(), mTextPaint);
            }
        }

        if (mBitmapToDraw != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapToDraw, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are setting text dynamically, you will need to reset `mBitmapToDraw` in order to get it refreshed.

Comment: can you provide any sample for ahieving all this.

Comment: I made the component with minimum needed code. Text aligment is not supported there, but you can achieve it checking gravity, measuring text height and width versus view size etc.

Comment: its not working for me,text is not displayed. only transparent rectangular image is dispalyed

Comment: What platform and device?

Comment: Galaxy nexus, Android 4.2

Comment: For me this works with Nexus 5 4.4 and HTC Wildfire 2.x, how do you use the component in your code?

Comment: <com.example.dynamicscroll.TransparentTextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dndView"
          
            
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
             
         />  TransparentTextView ttv = (TransparentTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
                  
                  ttv.setup();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44316/discussion-between-niko-and-user1891910)

Comment: Okay my proxy is blocking chat, does it work if you set text in xml?